# Redux initial state full of null values in Angular

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have worked on a project for about 10 months now, which is based on **Angular 4+** and Redux ( through **angular-redux/store** ). This project has been mostly successful, it's live in production since January and it doesn't experience any serious issue.

But... I have been gradually disappointed with Redux on one issue I consider at least annoying, but potentially bad for maintenance: the **initial state** with `null` values, so, I would like to find out what I'm doing wrong - or if that's a problem on Redux design *per se*.

### How to reproduce it

Here is a simple and good example of it: https://github.com/marinho/example-app

You just clone, `npm install` it, then run `npm run ng serve` and load **localhost:4200** on browser. Then go to **Console** and filter for "111" to see two lines:

```
11111 undefined
11112 null
```

That's printed by two observable subscriptions which are respectively watching values on `myUndefined` and `myObjects.country`. The first is an invalid key (wasn't initialised on the global state), the second was initialised with `null`.

The more precise location of these subscriptions is here: https://github.com/marinho/example-app/blob/master/src/app/component.ts#L15

### Why it happens

As we know, on Redux, one must `configureStore` with an initial state. Such initial state is a big tree with all possible keys as initialised by their reducers. By the initialisation time, no action was ran, neither reducer had any payload to resolve, so they default to `null` in most cases.

Until here, standard Redux/Angular, AFAIK.

Now, my two subscriptions (`myUndefined$` and `myObjects$`) observe `AnonymousSubject` instances, which are the channel provided by **angular-redux/store** to emit new values updated on a key path (i.e. `@select(['myObjects', 'city'])` means `<AppState>.myObjects.city`).

The problem is, as the initial state is initialised, there are new values **on all known state keys**, but almost all of them are assigned with `null`.

### Solution or hack?

Once there are subscriptions listening to any of these keys, such `null` will be emitted as the first value, which makes me need null checks such as `.filter(x => x !== null)` or similar in too many places. That's really ugly.

The alternative is to use **Epics** ( from **redux-observables** ), but they must be well designed and the result smells a mix of fragile with a not-so-reliable stack.

My impression is that this is not just a problem on **angular-redux/store** itself but actually a side effect of having a global state.

A simple solution could be to fix **angular-redux/store** to only start emitting values once the key isn't `undefined` anymore and so, avoid initialising keys with `null` and just prefer to not initialise them at all. But again, if that's a problem of Redux, I'm not sure this would be the right way to go.

So, is there anyone experiencing the same or has an elegant solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my mind this is inherent to Redux. Conceptually, Redux is an architecture which encourages you to think of your UI as a pure computation of the entire state at any given time. Your whole app is one big state machine.  So if you set an initial value of `null`, the first value of that selection will be `null`. If you don't set an initial value for a field at all, then the first value of the corresponding selection will be `undefined`.

This way, Redux kind of 'flattens time' in your app and factors it out. There's only the current state and the next action. This fundamental assumption is what makes the debugging tools so powerful.

We could have our Observables 'wait until the first non-nil value' until firing, but that's exactly the kind of temporal dependency I personally use Redux to avoid. My feeling is that making this change in the Angular-Redux/store library is probably not the right call, given that other people are probably not expecting it. I'm also not sure what effect it would have on time travel and other debug tools.

So in your case, what are some cleaner ways to handle these situations?

Generally I would consider one of the following:

1) make sure your reducers always have an initial state.

This works for cases where you do in fact have a reasonable up-front value for a key. So for whatever reducer controls `state.myUndefined`, you do

```
const INITIAL_VALUE = 'some-reasonable-value';
const myUndefinedReducer = (state = 'some-reasonable-value', action) => {
    // etc.
};
```

This way you're encoding the default value in the reducer itself.

2) Handle it on selection

This works for selections that aren't directly tied to a store property (e.g. they are the result of some RxJS computations). It also works for cases where the initial value of the key is dynamic, e.g. a value that's `undefined` until an API call fills it in or similar.

As you have noted, this essentially boils down to doing filters in several places, which can be verbose. However in your example, you could implement it more cleanly using [`select$`](https://angular-redux.github.io/store/globals.html#select_) and a [`Transformer`](https://angular-redux.github.io/store/globals.html#transformer):

Some Utils file:

```
export const skipNil = (obs$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> =>
    obs$.filter(v => v !== null && v !== undefined);
```

Component.ts:

```
@select$('myUndefined', skipNil) myUndefined$: Observable<any>;
@select$(['myObjects', 'country'], skipNil) country$: Observable<any>;
```

Comment: Thank you, looks reasonable. Btw the ideal setup sounds to be a mix of 1 and 2, as ideally should be none or as least as possible `null` values in initial state, indeed.

My point was that the first `undefined` should never emit, as that means the key is emitted before any reducer updated it, but yep, indeed that would be tricky for existing apps and even against the Redux approach, somehow.

I didn't know about `select$` though. Gonna use it more often where I can't give a non-null value on initial state.